# Getting rid of "warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF" when setting core.safecrlf to false doesn't work

Tags: git

I am trying to `git bisect` a codebase to find the source of a problem.

When checking out older revisions, a file is getting modified due to eol issues:

```
$ git status
HEAD detached at v1.9.3
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   ports/stm32/usbdev/Release_Notes.html
```

Because of this change, `git bisect` gets stuck:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        ports/stm32/usbdev/Release_Notes.html
Aborting
```

I am working with historical commits in an upstream codebase so I
can't modify `.gitattributes` nor can I modify the file and rebase
everything.

I've tried setting `core.safecrlf` to `false` in this repository:

```
git config core.safecrlf false
```

...but that doesn't seem to have had any impact on this problem. Is there any way to override Git's behavior with respect to this file without modifying files in the repository itself?

Comment: There's no config to deal with this, as far as I can tell. I have not run into the problem yet myself but I expect the trick is to just remove the file before `git bisect <good|bad>`.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that wasn't intuitive!  You should just post that as an answer, because it totally was the answer.

Comment: OK. It's an *ugly* answer because removing a file that *isn't* going to get checked out by the next bisect step, is a wrong thing to do, so you can't just clean away files even if they have CRLF changes. It also means that you may be testing against files with different line endings than were in effect historically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I admit this is kind of ugly and terrible, but it seems to work (see comments): for each file that Git complains about, simply *remove* the work-tree copy.  For instance, after:

```
git bisect good
```

(or the same with `bad`), you got this complaint about `ports/stm32/usbdev/Release_Notes.html`.  So:

```
rm ports/stm32/usbdev/Release_Notes.html
git bisect good  # or bad
```

Git will now feel free to switch to the next commit to be tested.

Do not blindly remove all files, since the `git checkout` of the next commit will *not* extract files that are the same in the current and next commit.  Bisect really should have a way to pass `-f` to the `git checkout` step, to handle the case where `git reset --hard HEAD` still leaves modified files due to end-of-line issues.  Well, that, or Git should have a more general method of dealing with "file in repository can never match work-tree due to end of line issues" cases.

Comment: Since it's just this one file and it's only documentation, removing it is going to be harmless. Thanks for the pointer!